# bash append text with special character and newline to file at specific line

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing

im trying to append a code text to a file, the code looks like

```
@ReactMethod
public void printBarCode(String str, int nType, int nWidthX, int nHeight,
          int nHriFontType, int nHriFontPosition) {
    byte[] command = PrinterCommand.getBarCodeCommand(str, nType, nWidthX, nHeight, nHriFontType, nHriFontPosition);
    sendDataByte(command);
}
```

and i put that to a variable called print_config

what i did was

```sh
sed -i "436 i $print_config" $file
# error
sed: -e expression #1, char 25: extra characters after command
```

i did an "\n" at the end of the line and it didnt make a newline but instead `@ReactMethod 'n' public void ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is the text contained in `print_config` has unescaped newlines in the file. Specifically you are attempting multi-line insert of:

```
@ReactMethod
public void printBarCode(String str, int nType, int nWidthX, int nHeight,
          int nHriFontType, int nHriFontPosition) {
    byte[] command = PrinterCommand.getBarCodeCommand(str, nType, nWidthX, nHeight, nHriFontType, nHriFontPosition);
    sendDataByte(command);
}
```

You cannot do that without preceding each newline with a `'\'` character. From `man sed` you have `"i \ text  Insert text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash."`

Instead, you may be better served by saving the contents above to a temporary file and then using the `r filename` command to `"Append text read from filename"`. In your case you would have:

```
sed -i '436r tempfile' file_to_modify
```

That would read the contents of `tempfile` into `file_to_modify` at line `436` without having to modify the text to escape each newline with a backslash.

Comment: if i have 2 configs 
Do i have to make 2 files ?

Comment: That would be the simplest way to handle it. Otherwise, you will need to essentially use `sed` twice for each insertion. Once to escape the newlines with backslashes in the text to be inserted, and two to actually insert the text. Two temporary files is an easier and less problematic way to go.